# RegExp Exclude Matches between Code and Pre Tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a gulp plugin to relativize URLs dynamically, but obviously want to avoid altering any references inside `<code>` or `<pre>` tags. The plugin searches for references in a certain format, but without negative look-behinds in Javascript regular expressions, I'm not sure how to exclude references inside `<code>` or `<pre>`.

Right now, my regular expression is like follows. Is there a way for me to edit it to either exclude URLs between `<code>` or `<pre>`, or to include those tags with the match for filtering after-the-fact?

```
var handle = /*handle for referential directory*/;
var search = new RegExp('(?:=|url\()\s?[\'\"](' + handle + ')\/\/(\S+)[\'\"]\s?(?:\))?','g');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PCRE-compatible regexes, the simple way is to use `<code>.*?</code>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|http.......` (where `.......` is your preferred URL-detecting regex) but JS has no such luxury.

However, what you can do is...

```
result = input.replace(/(<code>.*?<\/code>)|(http.....)/g,function(m,code,url) {
    if( code) return code; // code block, leave unchanged
    // do something with url here
});
```